# How does the structure of tendons change as they become stronger?

Tags: human-biology, tendons

I understand the [basic structure of tendons](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/85109/630), but I wonder how a tendon becomes stronger via exercise. Do the collagen fibers become more aligned/numerous/dense/etc.? Is the tendon expected to become thicker as it gets stronger? Does the cellular content of the tendons somehow change (e.g., more tenocytes, or higher quality tenocytes)? What other factors have a role in tendon strengthening?