# What causes tenocytes to migrate from intact regions of tendon into the wound site, and how do they move?

Tags: human-biology, movement, tendons

The 2018 study {1} mentions that:

> The healing process
>   of injured tendons includes tenocyte migration which occurs
>   from intact regions of tendon into the wound site.

What causes tenocytes to migrate from intact regions of tendon into the wound site, and how do they move?

---

References:

- {1} Dursun, Gözde, Mersedeh Tohidnezhad, Bernd Markert, and Marcus Stoffel. "Effects of uniaxial stretching on tenocyte migration behaviour." Current Directions in Biomedical Engineering 4, no. 1 (2018): 313-317. https://doi.org/10.1515/cdbme-2018-0076